# Ember.js and Zurb Foundation 5 - Nav Menu toggle takes to homepage and does not toggle.

Tags: ember.js, zurb-foundation

When I decrease the screen size and it switches to a mobile view, the Menu toggle button does not open the menu, but takes me to the main page.

```
<nav class="top-bar" data-topbar>
  <ul class="title-area">
    <li class="name">
      <h1>{{#link-to 'index'}}Welcome :{{/link-to}}</h1>
    </li>
    <li class="toggle-topbar menu-icon"><a href="#">Menu</a></li>
  </ul>
  <section class="top-bar-section">
    <ul class='right'>
      <li>
        {{#link-to 'main.users'}}Users{{/link-to}}
      </li>
      <li>
        {{#link-to 'main.org'}}Organizations{{/link-to}}
      </li>
    </ul>
  </section>
</nav>
```

Comment: You need to add the foundation nav event listeners to nav when ember inserts the nav into the dom.

Comment: Yeah man, I'm pretty new to Ember, you're going to have to give me an example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have your navigation in your application.hbs then you can use didInsertElement hook in the application view to hookup your foundation events.

You  will need to have loaded the foundation dependences I have this answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18881675/how-do-i-add-foundation-with-grunt-to-a-ember-js-app-kit-project/18882143#18882143).

```
App.ApplicationView = Em.View.extend({

  didInsertElement: function() {
    this.$().foundation('topbar');
  },

  willDestroyElement: function() {
    this.$().foundation('topbar', 'off');
  }
});
```

Here is a working [JSBin](http://jsbin.com/bemuf/2/edit)

Cheers

Comment: Humm, I actually have my navbar as a partial inserted into my routes. So I have an `index` and a `main` route. I tried creating an `App.IndexView` but it didnt take. The odd thing is I dont get any errors.

Comment: I just updated the answer and made a js bin for you. You don't need to have the nav in a partial for every page you can add it to the top of the nested routes.

Comment: Ahh I was forgetting the `this.` . N00b move

Comment: @kiwiupover you're missing the `$` inside willDestroyElement method, as in `this.$()`